# Remove all member roles and return them back some time later

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I need to remove all member roles and return them back later, I had started working on it but when I had executed this function (just writing command to Discord chat), I got following message: `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`

And here's the code I executed:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='e!')
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.command()
async def hardmute(ctx, time : str, member : discord.Member = None):
    if time[-1]=='s':
        tme = int(time[:-1])
    elif time[-1]=='m':
        tme = int(time[:-1])*60
    elif time[-1]=='h':
        tme = int(time[:-1])*60*60
    elif time[-1]=='d':
        tme = int(time[:-1])*60*60*60*24
    else:
        tme = False
    permissionrole = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=544069068777324579)
    hardmutedrole = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=717877658259554396)
    if member is None and tme and not ctx.author.roles[-1] >= ctx.guild.me.roles[-1]:
        await ctx.channel.send('{}, you're going to be hardmuted for {}'.format(ctx.author.mention, time))
        roles = ctx.author.roles
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(*ctx.author.roles)
        await ctx.author.add_roles(hardmutedrole)
        await asyncio.sleep(tme)
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(hardmutedrole)
        await ctx.author.add_roles(*roles)
        await ctx.channel.send('{} came back from hardmute!'.format(ctx.author.mention))
    elif member is not None and tme and not member.roles[-1] >= member.guild.me.roles[-1]:
        if permissionrole in ctx.author.roles:
            await ctx.channel.send('{}, you're going to be hardmuted for {}'.format(member.mention, time))
            roles = member.roles
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            await member.remove_roles(*ctx.author.roles)
            await member.add_roles(hardmutedrole)
            await asyncio.sleep(tme)
            await member.remove_roles(hardmutedrole)
            await member.add_roles(*roles)
            await ctx.channel.send('{} came back from hardmute!'.format(member.mention))
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send('You dont have permission role')
    elif ctx.author.roles[-1] >= ctx.guild.me.roles[-1] and member is None:
        await ctx.channel.send('{}, you have a role "{}", that is high or equal in role hierarchy than "{}"'.format(ctx.author.mention, ctx.author.roles[-1].name, ctx.guild.me.roles[-1].name))
    elif ctx.author.roles[-1] >= member.guild.me.roles[-1]:
        await ctx.channel.send('User {} have role "{}", that is high or equal in role hierarchy than "{}"'.format(member.name, member.roles[-1].name, ctx.guild.me.roles[-1].name))

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: In which line did you get the error?

Comment: `await ctx.author.remove_roles(*ctx.author.roles)` and with `add_roles` is the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure but `ctx.author.roles` returns a list, and you tried to remove role from list, you can try this instead:

```
roles = member.roles
await asyncio.sleep(3)
for role in ctx.author.roles:
    await member.remove_roles(role)
await member.add_roles(hardmutedrole)
await asyncio.sleep(tme)
await member.remove_roles(hardmutedrole)
for role in roles:
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role` - It's all the same, I think that script might not finding role due to internal discord problems

Comment: Change `get` to the `discord.utils.get` in these codes `permissionrole = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=544069068777324579)
    hardmutedrole = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=717877658259554396)`  and be sure that the id of that role is exist.